# What happened to the home-wiring tag?

Tags: support, moderation, tags, retagging

I just noticed that the [home-wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-wiring) tag has disappeared. From the sudden jump in the number of [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) questions, I presume it was moderator-merged into that tag and -- maybe -- black-listed.

A request: could we have some advance notice of such tag merges in the future?  If I'd known, I would have made the case that [home-wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-wiring) and [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring) are better synonyms.  To my mind, [wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiring) applies to the wires themselves -- installing, repairing, etc. -- whereas [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) applies to their use to carry electrical power, data signals, audio signals, etc. (I admit it's a fine distinction).

Have other tags been merged and/or black-listed recently, and is there a way for us regular users to see these merges and black-listings?

Answer (score 4):

I merged them because “home-wiring” seemed redundant (this site is all about homes) and there was no clear difference between questions tagged “home-wiring” and questions tagged “electrical”.

They are the only tags I merged. Perhaps I should have discussed it on meta first. I didn't because I didn't think it would be controversial, just a janitorial task.

I don't understand why you think it's necessary to have both tags. Is there anyone what would follow “home-wiring” but not “electrical“?

Comment: There may have been some questions about non-electrical wiring caught up in the merge (networking, speaker cable, etc).  If I see any, I'll retag them as wiring instead of electrical.

Comment: @BMitch, thanks